# Strange exceptions ocurring

Tags: 2010, feature

I am having very big trouble with features, my feature has the following
site columns
content type
list tempalte
list instance

After fighting a lot, I removed the feature and created them again in Visual Studio.
When I did this, then in Sharepoint I have 2 lists on the menu, but when I click on them, there is an exception, the log says:

1. Failed to determine the setup path of the list schema for feature ID. ... feature.xml

I wanted to try removing everything manually, but when I was trying to delete the content type it says it belongs to an application feature

Comment: In my opinion is trying to find the old feature.xml, but that feature does not even exist anymore because I deleted it from visual studio....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iisreset or retract solution, check that the file instance has an attribute called populated FeatureId, if you want write me via mail

Comment: can you do skype?

Comment: i prefer that you send me email with the code, for example

Comment: whats your email, its not on your profile.